# The installation dialog box does not show up after booting from my bootable USB which has Ubuntu in it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, usb, syslinux

I used to create bootable USBs in the following way and it used to work perfectly fine:

1. `sudo mount -o loop /path to iso/ /media/iso`
2. `cp -a /media/iso/. /path to usb flash drive/`
3. `sudo syslinux -s /dev/sdX`
4. And then renaming the isolinux folder to sylinux and the isolinux.cfg file inside it to syslinux.cfg

But now when I boot from my USB, the ubuntu system boots and hangs on one screen. Everything shows up except the Installation Dialog Box where I have to click the install button.

Please help.

The Ubuntu ISO was created using remastersys by the way.

Edit 1:

And even when I tried to make the USB bootable using usb-creator-gtk, it went till 99%, asked for password to install the BootLoader and then said "Failed to install BootLoader".

Comment: Could be a lot of things. Knowing your your PC's tech specs and version of Ubuntu may help others narrow down the possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the correct and stable way for creating custom ubuntu distros.

1. Clone this Git repo:

   https://github.com/Distroshare/distroshare-ubuntu-imager.git
2. Edit the `distroshare-ubuntu-imager.config` file inside it and change the destination directory of the created ISO if you want.
3. Run the script inside it using `sudo ./distroshare-ubuntu-imager.sh` and it will create the ISO for you as specified in the config file.
4. Use `Unetbootin` to create bootable USB and VIOLA! You are done!

Now install this Custom Distro by booting through your USB.